# How do I use composite key user ids with Catalyst::Plugin:: Authentication::DBI?

Tags: perl, authentication, catalyst

What is the most effective to way to make `Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication` work if the user uesrid is qualified by a domain (i.e. composite key)? Does it support this functionality? I'm looking specifically at using `Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication::DBI` but I'm not opposed to forking, patching, recreating it  if it doesn't have the current functionality.

I need to login to a certain domain name with a certain password. It seems as if /all/ the `C:P:A` modules depend on a simple UserID / Password combination. Other examples, and hints are welcome.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The real answer is `Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication` requires `from_session` and `for_user` to [handle only serialized keys](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/Catalyst-Plugin-Authentication/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Authentication/Internals.pod): `for_user` returning the serialized key, `from_session` returning the user. This creates an issue because `C:P:A:DBI` does not currently permit multi-key users in its role implementation or in its `from_session` and `for_user` implementation. Oddly, it does permit complex key-value conditionals in user-retrieval in find_user. Currently, the draw back is a bad assumption all users are identified with a uid/guid/pkid, etc..

In order to have a user identified with a composite key the query-conditional would have to be attached to the store, or cached in the `for_user` serialized key. Both, of these are doable with a patch.

Oddly enough I had this same confusion last time [I created an LDAP store 3 years ago](http://grokbase.com/topic/2007/02/19/catalyst-dev-bug-feature-request-in-c-p-a-backend/1fkgZMqXe-aXrsHDDtGZgaO7ttI/badsc4).

I'll keep this question open until I patch it, fork it, or someone gives useful applicable advice to `Catalyst::Plugin:: Authentication::Store::DBI`. I have rewritten this module and it is available at http://github.com/EvanCarroll/Catalyst-Authentication-Store-DBI

Comment: There's no such assumption in Auth, there's no such module as Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication::DBI, and if you're talking about Catalyst::Authentication::Store::DBI the answer should be obvious. `for_session` and `from_session` merely have to be inverses.

Comment: The assumption is in Store::DBI pertaining to users being unique on a single column and roles being retrieved with that single column.. Good catch on the module name typo.

Answer (score 7):

1. Catalyst::Authentication::Store::DBIx::Class supports finding a user on any sort of key you like, as all of the auth info you provide (with the exception of the designated password_field) is turned into a DB query, you can do `$c->authenticate({ last_name => "Fred", favorite_color => "Blue" })` if you want.
2. Pretty much anything you can imagine is possible if you write a [Realm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Catalyst::Authentication::Realm) or a [Store](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Catalyst::Authentication::Store), and there's no reason they have to be complicated -- just classes that implement one or two methods and inherit the rest. Which one you would have to use depends on the details of what your app is doing -- overriding `find_user` in a Realm would be the easier case; writing a new Store would be the slightly trickier one.